# Barrels - How to export a constant

Tags: typescript

I want to create a constant and export it using index.ts. But when I try to load the const using the index path instead the full const path, I get the error "Cannot find module `./form-validation`".

`app
└───...
└───translation
│   │   translation.service.ts
│   │
│   └───form-validation
│       │   pt-BR.ts
│       │   index.ts`

## Const file

pt-BR.ts

```
export const formValidationPtBr  = {
  "minlength" : "tamanho"
}
```

index.ts

```
export { formValidationPtBr } from './pt-BR';
```

## Working Structure

translation.service.ts

```
import { formValidationPtBr } from './form-validation/pt-BR'; // here the import os OK and I can access the const `formValidationPtBr`.

@Injectable()
export class TranslationService {

  constructor() {
    console.log(formValidationPtBr);
  }

}
```

## Wanted structure (Not working)

translation.service.ts

```
import { formValidationPtBr } from './form-validation'; // here the import desn't work saying "Cannot find module `./form-validation`"

@Injectable()
export class TranslationService {

  constructor() {
    console.log(formValidationPtBr);
  }

}
```

Comment: I thought Barrels were kind of going the way of the dodo, not recommended anymore and so on, in favor of modules. There was a technical reason for it, I remember reading it somewhere but can't remember it. Any reason not to just export the constant from a module?

Comment: The problem here is that I'll have many language files. And I would like to import all of them in a single line. If I need to give the full path I will end up with one line for each language...

Comment: Is there a reason you cant make a languages module that handles all of them? That way you'd keep it all in one line, and any time you have a new language, just add the constants to the module; the module could aggregate the individual language files, and just export all of them at once, or individually, e.g. import Spanish, French, Etc. from ./my.language.module'. Modules...they're not just for components anymore! If barrels works for you ideally that's great, but it seems modules are the preferred way these days, to the point that barrels aren't mentioned in the Angular world much anymore.

Comment: I think I need to change my logic... thanks for the tips!